# Android Testing Support Library not found with Espresso and different BuildVariants

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

We have three BuildVariants: `release`, `debug` and `develop`. The first are the defaults from `AndroidStudio`. The last is for our internal testing. Here are the configs: (There is nothing different than `Signing Config`)
[image]
[image]

We have imports the following in our `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // App dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
}
```

Now we've created the `androidTest/` folder (where the Espresso-Tests are located). I've looked at the example from the [Android-Testing Samples in GitHub.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/espresso/BasicSample)

But AndoridStudio says always "Cannot find Symbole" for AndroidJUnit4.class:
[image]

(And now, after a lot of explanation - sorry for that :D)
I found the issue. Our Build Variants was set on `Android Instrumented Tests` (which is ok) but the App-Module was on the `develop` `BuildVariant`. When we have changed it to `debug` all was fine.

Now I'm not sure if this a bug or is this normal?! Because we have no different - instead of the Singing Config (but I've tested it, it isn't the problem) - on the BuildVariants. And when it's normal, why?!

**Edit:**

I've created a AOSP-Ticket too: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my update on the bug. In short, you need this line:

```
android {
  testBuildType "develop"
}
```

Comment: Bit this is only a workaround or? In future releases it will be possible without this line?!

Comment: Apparently it's not just happening with custom build variants, but also within a library's default build types. In other words, I too am exhibiting the same behavior only when trying to use those classes in a test utility library. AS acts like its not being declared, even after forcing the testBuildType to "debug" in the library's gradle script.

Comment: @DiegoTori please file a bug on b.android.com with all the details (or comment on the one linked above)

Comment: Done. Please check the existing AOSP ticket.

Comment: Thanks! It's day saver!